# django restful filtering by derived field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was wondering if I can use a serializer to add two columns of a database, package it, and as a bonus FILTER by it.

## models.py

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    time1= models.DateTimeField()
    time2 = models.DateTimeField()
```

## serializers.py

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sometime= UnixEpochDateField(source  = 'time1') # special serializer that converts a datetime to epoch (below)
    sometime2= UnixEpochDateField(source  = 'time2') # special serializer that converts a datetime to epoch (below)

    sometime_SUM = sometime + sometime2 # THIS DOES NOT WORK!

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('sometime_SUM')

class UnixEpochDateField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def to_native(self, value):
        """ Return epoch time for a datetime object or ``None``"""
        import time
        try:
            return calendar.timegm(value.utctimetuple())
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return None

    def from_native(self, value):
        import datetime
        try:
            value = float(value)
        except:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not a number.  Input: %s %s"%(type(value), value))
        if value < 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Cannot be less than 0. Input: %s"%value)

        return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(value))
```

## views.py

```
class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    filter = ('sometime_SUM') # THIS DOES NOT WORK!
    def get(self, request, format='json'):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        filter = SnippetFilter(request.GET, queryset = snippets)  # THIS DOES NOT WORK!
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(filter, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have highlighted the code that doesn't work that I naively thought would work.
The url command I want to use is /someurl/snippets/?sometime_SUM>4

EDIT:
Apparently, I can't filter by a serialize field.  So let me modify my question to, can I filter by time1, except when I input the time from my website to the API, i am using EPOCH time, instead of the time1, DATETIME
Thanks @mariodev

Comment: You can't just filter a table by serializer value, your `sometime_SUM` needs to be actual Snippet field, so you can add both values on model's `save()` when adding new object (and edit if one of them is changed).

Comment: ok.  what if I just wanted to filter by time1, except when I am filtering, I want to filter by EPOCH times?  So isntead of filtering by sometime_SUM, i just want to filter by time1.  which in mysql is in DATETIME, when I input it, it is in EPOCH time.

Comment: What kind of filtering you are planning to do?

Comment: like get everything where 10 < time1 < 100
where again, 10 and 100 are in epoch time when it comes in from the API.  Where/how do i convert it so it can filter?